# Using -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 on async block crash on both MainContext and PrivateContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I've added -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 flag to my target.
The problem is that I have a background block that is running, and crashes when I'm using either  NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType

My Code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 NSManagedObjectContext *privateManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
 [privateManagedObjectContext setParentContext:_mainContext];
 [User fetchUserWithContext:_ privateManagedObjectContext];
}];
```

I've also tried:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 [User fetchUserWithContext:_mainContext];
}];
```

In both situations I get:

CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext **Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor**]:

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how Core Data queue concurrency works. When using either `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, you need to use the `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` methods on `NSManagedObjectContext` whenever you access the context. The fact that you're using GCD here is irrelevant; if you're using queue concurrency, you must use those methods, or you're doing it wrong.

You need to put your `fetchUserWithContext` call inside a block passed to one of those methods. You also need to put anything else that accesses objects fetched from the context inside a block passed to one of those methods.

Comment: I guest that was the missing part. Thank you!